# minikube - E0410 - start.go:159] Error starting host: Error starting stopped host: Machine didn't return an IP after 120 seconds, aborting

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Why am I getting this error when starting minikube?

```
minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit --disk-size=2g
Starting local Kubernetes v1.9.4 cluster...
Starting VM...
E0410 16:26:12.652851    6972 start.go:159] Error starting host: Error starting stopped host: Machine didn't return an IP after 120 seconds, aborting.
```

and how would you fix it?

Comment: check this thread, https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/521

Comment: That is a common error. Can you run minikube with the `--loglevel=0 -v 4` and post the log somewhere?

Comment: please refer here for solution to similar issue [minikube error troubleshooting........](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52300055/error-restarting-cluster-restarting-kube-proxy-waiting-for-kube-proxy-to-be-up/52740196#52740196)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried 
`minikube delete` followed by `minikube start --vm-driver=hyperkit` (or are you using another driver)?