# Error restarting cluster: restarting kube-proxy: waiting for kube-proxy to be up for configmap update: timed out waiting for the condition

Tags: kubernetes, devops, minikube

I am trying to start a local Kubernetes cluster using `minikube start` and getting the following error.

```
Starting local Kubernetes v1.10.0 cluster...
Starting VM...
Getting VM IP address...
Moving files into cluster...
Setting up certs...
Connecting to cluster...
Setting up kubeconfig...
Starting cluster components...
E0912 17:39:12.486830   17689 start.go:305] Error restarting 
cluster:  restarting kube-proxy: waiting for kube-proxy to be 
up for configmap update: timed out waiting for the condition
```

Any idea how to ensure it starts? I am using VirtualBox and [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/) tutorial. I tried the tip given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49899216/restarting-kube-proxy-wating-for-conditions) but without luck.

Also any specific reason why it takes so long to even reach to this stage? Or is it usually this slow?

Comment: What distribution are you using for the minikube? The tutorial you've linked is for Mac, did you follow the instruction from the official Kubernetes documentation about [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/) and what version of the minikube did you install? You could also check in verbose mode what is causing the issue:
`minikube delete`
`minikube start -v=2`
I would also check if there is maybe an active firewall. But first we need some more details about the environment.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

following are the points to be remembered while starting minikube for such errors.

1) close the **VirtualBox** if opened. 
2) delete the previous **temp** files generated.
3) if you are behind the proxy **set the proxy**.
4) then do the following...

```
    $ minikube stop
    $ minikube delete  
    $ minikube start
```

Answer (score 0):

Below steps works for me :

Note : Do not work with **root** user

```
$ sudo minikube stop

$ sudo minikube delete

$ sudo rm -rf ~/.minikube

$ sudo minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.12.4
```

you can specify any existing kubernetes version of your choice with prefix **v** compulsory

make sure **.minikube** directory created in users home directory but not in **/root**